# How to launch an app at startup in minimized mode?

Tags: settings, startup, minimize

I want to start the default mail application at startup in minimized mode. While the System settings app allows applications to be added to launch at startup, there is no option to start the specified application in a minimized window. How can be this be done?

I am a newcomer to Linux, thus I would request the answers to be a little verbose, since my technical knowledge of Linux is limited.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Pantheon Mail will start in the background after startup if you select the option to always check for new mail. This way you'll always get a notification when the new mail arrives.

If I'm wrong, there is a pantheon-mail-autostart.desktop in /usr/share/applications folder so you may try to autostart this file instead of org.pantheon.mail.desktop

Hope this helps.